# Incorrect NIntegrate result with "LocalAdaptive" method and several rules

Tags: numerical-integration

The integration is simple and doesn't have any singularity,

```
NIntegrate[1/(x^2 + 1), {x, 0, 10}]
```

The `"GlobalAdaptive"` method or analytical integration can provide the correct result as `1.47113`..., the `"LocalAdaptive"` method without any rule can also provide the correct result. But if I use the `"ClenshawCurtisOscillatoryRule"`, or `"GaussBerntsenEspelidRule"` with `"LocalAdaptive"` method, the result is incorrect. For that with `"ClenshawCurtisOscillatoryRule"`, the expression I used is,

```
NIntegrate[1/(x^2 + 1), {x, 0, 10}, MaxRecursion -> 30, Method -> 
    {"LocalAdaptive",   Method -> "ClenshawCurtisOscillatoryRule"},
     AccuracyGoal -> 12, PrecisionGoal -> 10]
```

The result is `1.33558`. The result with `"GaussBerntsenEspelidRule"` is even smaller as `1.2844`.

I wonder if this is a bug or something I didn't appreciate?

Comment: In short: `"ClenshawCurtisOscillatoryRule"` is adapted to and appropriate for *finite, oscillatory* integrals. Your integrand is not oscillatory. (To borrow an engineering analogy, you're using it "out of spec", so no surprise that you're getting junk.)

Comment: Why are you forcing different rules? This is something you shouldn't mess with unless you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

You need to increase the `MinRecursion` value:

```
In[37]:= NIntegrate[1/(x^2 + 1), {x, 0, 10}, MinRecursion -> 12, 
 MaxRecursion -> 30, 
 Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", 
   Method -> "ClenshawCurtisOscillatoryRule"}, AccuracyGoal -> 12, 
 PrecisionGoal -> 10]

Out[37]= 1.47113
```

What is happening is explained in the section ["Local Adaptive integration"](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html#19475523) in the [advanced NIntegrate documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html). "LocalAdaptive" has an initialization stage in which a rough estimate is computed, and that estimate is used to decide to proceed or not with the recursive sub-division.

Comment: @yiboyang No problem, good luck!